# retrofit2 parse a multiline json response

Tags: java, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to consume from an API that streams JSON object, one per line, using retrofit2.
The response look something like this

```json
{"key":" value", ...}
{"key":" value", ...}
{"key":" value", ...}
{"key":" value", ...}
{"key":" value", ...}
{"key":" value", ...}
```

I tried to use Gson converter and set lenient to true so it could support json multiline objects, with something like this:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
  .setLenient()
  .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .client(okHttpClient)
  .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
  .build();
```

and my API interface, I tried this

```java
public interface Api {

    @Streaming
    @POST("/stream")
    @Headers({"accept: application/stream+json", "content-type: application/json"})
    Call<Response>
    generateStream2(@Body Request request);
}
```

but it seems Gson converter is not able to consume the whole response, I get an `JSON document was not fully consumed.` exception when trying to read the reponse.

Also tried using `Call<List<Response>>` but gson converter fails saying it expected `[` but got `{`.

Is there a way to automatically generate/convert a list of those objects?

Answer (score 0):

I've end not a great solution to just accept a string response and then manually converting the lines to my objects. So my `Api.java` becomes like this:

```java
public interface Api {

    @Streaming
    @POST("/stream")
    @Headers({"accept: application/stream+json", "content-type: application/json"})
    Call<String>
    generateStream2(@Body Request request);
}
```

Then when receiving response a parse it like this

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
api.generateStream2(request).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<String>() {
    @Override public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
        String[] lines = response.body().split("\n");
        for(String line: lines) {
            Response resp = gson.fromJson(line, Response.class);
        }
    }
}
```